# Unable to dynamically set a string of text using useState in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can anyone advise why this isn't working?

```
export default function App() {
  const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('rts');
  const [buttonName, setButtonName] = useState('RTS / MPC DSP');

  const switchButtons = (x) => {
    setButtonStatus(x);
  };

  const displayButtons = () => {
    if (buttonStatus === 'rts') {
      setButtonName('RTS / MPC DSP');
      return <RTSButtons />;
    } else if (buttonStatus === 'rtb') {
      setButtonName('RTB');
      return <RTBButtons />;
    } else if (buttonStatus === 'mpc') {
      setButtonName('MPC');
      return <MPCButtons />;
    }
  };
```

I want to use `setButtonName` to adjust the name of the button collection here:

```
<h2 className='font-bold text-2xl capitalize -mb-10 mt-2'>{buttonName}</h2>
```

But it seems that it either sometimes get just a blank screen when the conditions are met or an infinite loop error message. Is it because I should be doing

```
return <RTSButtons />, setButtonName('RTS / MPC DSP')
```

This that is possible?

Comment: Why aren't you passing button name as props to `RTSButtons` component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, modifying the state (e.g. your `setButtonName` call) and rendering components (React (indirectly) calling `App()`) need to be separate. If you try to modify the state during rendering, React will indeed throw an error.

In your case, you can calculate `buttomName` during rendering, without having to store it in a state variable:

```js
export default function App() {
    const [buttonStatus, setButtonStatus] = useState('rts');
  
    const switchButtons = (x) => {
      setButtonStatus(x);
    };

    let buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
    let buttons;
    if (buttonStatus === 'rts') {
        buttonName = 'RTS / MPC DSP';
        buttons = <RTSButtons />;
    } else if (etc) {
        // ... etc
    }

    // Example usage
    return <>
        <h2 className='font-bold text-2xl capitalize -mb-10 mt-2'>{buttonName}</h2>
        {buttons}
    </>;
}
```